# Does Windows 10 Free Upgrade has expiration date?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I am getting popup on my Win 7 machine peddling me free Windows 10 Upgrade..

It says somewhere (I think I clicked on some link with small print) that this offer will expire. But it dont say when.

Anyone knows if those free Win 10 upgrades have expiration date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [website](http://www.howtogeek.com/226100/the-windows-10-faq-everything-you-need-to-know/), it's free for the first year (after the release of Windows 10), until 28/07/2016.

Edit: As suggested, adding a bit more info.

> the upgrade is only free for the first year Windows 10 is available. Windows 10 was officially released in 07/29/2015 and the upgrade will remain free for qualifying users until 07/28/2016.
>
> If you’re building a new PC and need a brand new Windows license you can purchase Windows 10 for $119 (or Windows 10 Pro for $199). Practically speaking though, buying a full price Windows 10 key, of either flavor, is a bad deal considering that you can purchase a cheaper key for Windows 7 and upgrade (or just scrounge it off the bottom of an old laptop or computer). You could, for example, buy a horribly dated (and possibly broken) Windows laptop at a garage sale for next to nothing and use the key to upgrade.
>
> Even if you don’t want to gamble on using a key off an old laptop that somebody else might have recorded for their own use, it’s still cheaper to buy an old version of Windows and upgrade it. You can buy a brand new copy of Windows 8.1 Pro for $131, for example, and upgrade it to Windows 10 Pro (saving yourself ~$70 in the process).

Comment: Your answer is a bit misleading, because it could imply that if I installed windows 7 or 8 today, I'd get to upgrade until dec 14th 2016, which is obvoulsy not the case.

Comment: To improve your answer, rather than just linking to the site, add the basic answer information quoted from the site. It would make it more clear.

Comment: Good point, and idea. Added a bit more information, thanks.

Comment: The part about scrounging an OEM key off the bottom of an old system and using that breaks the EULA and, depending where you live, the law